# Make images/PDFs in QGIS from Vector Layers

Tags: qgis, image, aerial-photography, orthophoto

I have a bunch of vector layers and a few polygons that I want to use to create a image out of while having my image in the background of an aerial photo.  I am unsure what commands to use to accomplish this.

Picture for reference.[image]

Comment: For a simple image, you can use `Project > Save as Image...`. For high resolution images or PDFs, you can use the **Print Composer** (`Project > New Print Composer`) :)